# Substituting nan values with mean code

Tags: python, data-science-model

```
for x in num_cols:
    imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
    imp.fit(np.array(ds[x]).reshape(-1,1))
    ds[x] = imp.transform(np.array(ds[x]).reshape(-1,1))
```

Comment: Welcome to DS StackExchange. Please elaborate more on your question, otherwise providing help il going to be difficult. What are you specifically trying to figure out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you are substituting the missing values (nans) with something, it can be either the most frequent data, median, average(mean), whatever. mean modifies the nan values with the average of not-nan values.

```py
for x in num_cols:
    imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')  
    imp.fit(np.array(ds[x]).reshape(-1,1)) 
    ds[x] = imp.transform(np.array(ds[x]).reshape(-1,1))
```

> `imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')`

For transforming missing values we use `SimpleImputer`, here, the missing values are `np.nan` and we want to use the `mean` strategy for transforming these nans. Thereby, their values would be substituted by the average value of each feature.

> `imp.fit(np.array(ds[x]).reshape(-1,1))`

You have an $n * m$ (`array (np.array(ds[x]))`), by `reshape(-1,1))` you convert it to shape $(m*n, 1)$ -1 here stands for vertical array and 1 stands for having one column.

Then you fit your transformer (imp) to your data `(np.array(ds[x]).reshape(-1,1))`

> `ds[x] = imp.transform(np.array(ds[x]).reshape(-1,1))`

Here, the transformed data would be substituted in ds[x]